# problem when an editor is also an author in jurabib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jurabib

I'm using `jurabib` to do the bibliography for my dissertation (I'm having to do the MHRA style and jurabib does this quite well).  The problem I have is as follows:  I have some books by author A and edited by person B.  I also have a book that is by person B.  I am using `bibformat=ibidem` which, in the bibliography section, lists the author once and then lists their works, replacing their name subsequently with a long dash.

However, after multiple occurences of editor B, the editor is also being replaced by a dash.  And then subsequently when the editor is an author, their name does not even appear once, in their first entry.  It has become a dash.  I use the following options:

```
\usepackage[
titleformat=italic,
citefull=first,
pages=always,
edby = true,
bibformat=ibidem,
crossref=short,
mhra
]{jurabib}
\jbbookedaftertitle
\jbdisablecitationcrossref
\jbedseplikecite
\jbdonotindexeditors
```

I'm quite happy for the editor to never be replaced by a dash, which would presumably fix the problem of them not appearing as an author.

Apologies for this somewhat subtle problem - though most latex ones appear to be that way :)

Comment: I'm not sure how many people are still using `jurabib` unfortunately. For this type of referencing style, `biblatex` is probably now the norm.  See this question [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693) for a general overview. It may be quite simple to implement your preferred citation/bib style using it. (I realize that this is not the kind of response you probably want to hear.)

Comment: The CTAN version of `jurabib` neither recognizes the `mhra` option nor features the behaviour you describe. A web search indicates that another package version may have been in development -- however, `jurabib`'s development has been abandoned by now. Please provide a link to your version of `jurabib`, or we'll have to close this question.